# Why models often benefit from reducing the learning rate during training

Tags: conv-neural-network, keras

In Keras official documentation for [ReduceLROnPlateau class](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/) they mention that

> Models often benefit from reducing the learning rate

Why is that so? It's counter-intuitive for me at least, since from what I know- a higher learning rate allows taking further steps from my current position, and if I'll reduce the LR I might never "escape" a certain minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more complete quote is:

> Models often benefit from reducing the learning rate by a factor of 2-10 **once learning stagnates.**

(my emphasis).

There are two main reasons why your learning might seem to be stuck:

1. You are around a local minimum and in every direction you might go you'd increase your error. In that case, as you correctly state, *increasing* the learning rate might allow you to "jump out" of the local minimum.
2. You are in a steep valley and are oscillating between the walls. At one point the gradient points steep left; you make a large step in that direction and find yourself on the other side with the gradient pointing steep right. You are basically jumping back and forth far above the minimum. Here, *decreasing* the learning rate might allow you to descend into the minimum.

The above quote refers to this second case.

Comment: With regards to 2nd point, does this apply even for optimizers such as SGD, mini-batch SGD or their momentum variants? I can understand the oscillations intuition for vanilla GD

Comment: @adosar That's a good question to which I don't know the answer. It seems to me that SGD and its variants might change the *direction* in which you're going, but the step size could still be too large and lead to the "opposite wall of the gorge". Maybe you should post your comment as a question.

Answer (score 0):

In ML methods where terms are added consequently (e.g. boosting) a learning rate below 1 is equivalent to shrinking coefficients of predictors towards 0. So reduced learning rate works for the same reason lasso and ridge regression work: *regularization*. In situations with high predictor-to-observation ratio, regularization reduces model variance at the expense of introducing a relatively small bias. Since the overall predictive error follows the rule
$$
\text{Mean-error Error} = \text{Bias}^2 + \text{Variance},
$$
the predictive error benefits from regularization.